# UIImageview is not showing image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

This is the code which i am using to display a PGM format image, it was working earlier and also it is working if i use it as a separate project but it is not working now, I am not able to figure out why it is not working. Someone please help me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
CGPoint center = self.view.center;
activityIndicator.frame= CGRectMake(center.x, center.y, 37, 37);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(center.x-30, center.y+40, 160, 30)];
[label setText:@"Calculating..."];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[self.view addSubview:label];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
/////////////// read file ///////////
    FILE *file = fopen("/Users/Sumit/Desktop/test/out.pgm", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"File Not Found");
        return;
    }
    char name[20], secondline[10];
    int w=0, h=0, colors=0;
    fscanf(file, "%s", name);
    fscanf(file, "%s", secondline);
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &w, &h, &colors);
    //printf("%d %d\n", w, h);
    unsigned char * imagedata = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*w*h);
    fseek(file, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    int i=0;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        int val = getc(file);
        imagedata[i] = val;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    ////////////////// end read file /////////////

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CFDataRef rgbData = CFDataCreate(NULL, imagedata, w * h);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(rgbData);
    CGImageRef rgbImageRef = CGImageCreate(w, h, 8, 8, w , colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CFRelease(rgbData);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
    UIImage * newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rgbImageRef];
    //imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x,imageview.frame.origin.y, w, h);
    [imageview setImage:newimage];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [label removeFromSuperview];

    CGSize boundsSize = scrollview.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = imageview.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    imageview.frame = frameToCenter;
    [scrollview addSubview:imageview];
    CGImageRelease(rgbImageRef);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });
});

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do every UI modifies on the main thread. You setting your image view.image on another thread. This is your problem.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageview.image = newimage;
});
```

Your actually code will effect that, your image won't set straightway after [imageview setImage:newimage];  line, because it's on a background thread. It will set sometime later.

Comment: Exactly! as a best practice all the UI mods should be done on the main thread!

Comment: i got your point but still it is not working, few days back it was working, i don't know how suddenly it stopped working

Comment: check that your new image is not nil, and set your image view.backgroundcolor to orange for example, to make sure your image view is in the right place with the right width and height.

Comment: are you sure your image view width and height is not 0 ?

Comment: yeah, height and width is not 0, even i tried backgroundcolor as red but it not showing anything

Comment: so the problem is your image view is not in that position as you want

Comment: ah nice answer!